# What can cause powered, but not functional Wipers, 2012 VW Passat?

Tags: electrical, vw, windshield-wipers, passat

A few weeks ago my wipers started acting up when raining. The wipers will suddenly stop working. It happened about 3-4 times or so, and stopping the car, powering it off, opening the door, closing the door, and starting again fixed it once or twice. But the other few times the wipers started working the next day as that is when I tried them again.

I am sharing the Wiring Diagrams, Fuse Diagrams and Relay Diagrams for the 2012 VW Passat below.

- Fuse `SB20` has power.

  - 40A fuse, Orange Located at `Fuse panel B -SB`.

    - The fuse is not blown.
  - When the car was powered off it has about 12V across.
  - When the car was turned on, and wipers' handle was turned on - it had about 13.8V.
- Relays

  - Diagram `Relay Carrier 1 -SR1- , from January 2011`
  - Wiper motor change-over relay 1 -J368-
  - Wiper motor change-over relay 2 -J369-
  - Originally installed, I had 2x Blue color `650` Relays; part number `8X0951253`.
  - I replaced them with brand new Green color `655` relays; part number `8X0951253*A*`.
  - On `Wiper motor relay 2 -J369- (650)`:

    - When the car is turned on, but the wipers' handle is not (wipers `OFF`, in cabin), the Fuse has (-13.9V) across terminals 5 to 1 and 5 to 4 and (-13.9V) across 2 to 4.
    - When the car is turned on, but the wipers' handle is (wipers `ON`, in cabin), terminals 5 to 2 and 5 to 4 have (-13.5V)
  - On `Wiper motor relay 1 -J368- (650)`:

    - When the car is turned on, but the wipers' handle is not (wipers `OFF`, in cabin), the Fuse has (+13.9V) across terminals 5 to 2 and 5 to 4 and (-13.9V) across 2 to 4 and 2 to 1.
    - When the car is turned on, but the wipers' handle is (wipers `ON`, in cabin), terminals 5 to 1 have (+13.5V)
- Control Handle (cabin)

  - I took the cover from the steering column. The connects at the base are not loose. Also, the same Cabin handle that controls the wipers controls the windshield water sprayers, and those work. So I am assuming that its not the steering column connector, or the controller handle itself.
- Wiper Motor

  - Motor Part # 561.955.119.A
  - Entire Assembly Part # 561.955.023B
  - I have ordered a second hand wiper motor assembly from eBay, and replaced the motor. It did not fix the issue.
  - I have applied 12V (from a DIY power supply) to the two edge pins in the Wiper Motor connector, and the motor was moving.
  - Regardless of the Wipers being turned on or off (from the cabin), the voltage across the edge pins of the Wiper Motor connector (in the car) is 13.8V. There is no voltage across the other pins at all, regardless of wiper's being turned on or off.

**Everything seems to be in order, or at least I think so. What am I missing? What can cause this behavior? Are there any other things I can check?**

**Update #1:**
As a note, not sure if its related or not. But, a long time ago I have installed a dashcam, it is taking its power from a piggyback connector Fuse `SC42`. It is the Cigarette Light -U1- 12V Socket. And recently I started hearing the Dashcam complaining that the rear-view camera is disconnect and then connected again, and it would repeat 2x or 3x times and then stop. It happens when driving, and I was not able to correlate that with any pothole bumps, acceleration, or stopping (not yet at least). The reason I bring it up is because it also resides on the 12V line (not sure if its the same line as the wiper motor).

`Wiring Diagram`
[image]
[image]

`Fuse panel F (SF) ["from January 2011"]`
[image]

`Fuse panel C (SC) ["from December 2011"]`
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

`Circuit breaker`
[image]

`Fuse panel B (SB) ["from December 2011"]`
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

`Fuse panel A (SA) ["from January 2011"]`
[image]
[image]

`Relay Carrier 1 -SR1- , from January 2011`
[image]

`Relay Carrier 2 -SR2- , from January 2011`
[image]

`Relay Carrier 3 -SR3- , from January 2011`
[image]

Comment: You said it "started acting up", but you never really said what that means. Do they just stop working all together? Or do the run erratically (on again off again)? What do they do when they are not working as expected?

Comment: Does the motor spin when it should? You could have a mechanical linkage issue rather than an electrical one.

Comment: By acting up i meant that there just stopped working. In the middle of window sometime. And only started working after power cycling the car. But over time they are not working anymore. Now nothing helps.

Comment: The motor doesn't spin at all.